# Divide the polynomials $(x^6-18x^4+42x^3+9x^2+19x+13):(x^3+5x^2+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Divide the polynomials $(x^6-18x^4+42x^3+9x^2+19x+13):(x^3+5x^2+3)$

I've tried factorizing the two polynomials, but I've gotten nowhere from it. It seems like you can't use the rational zero theorem or I've done something wrong. Either way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use polynomial long division?

Comment: Check your work with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polynomialquotientremainder%5B%28x%5E6-18x%5E4%2B42x%5E3%2B9x%5E2%2B19x%2B13%29%2C%28x%5E3%2B5x%5E2%2B3%29%2Cx%5D).

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't aware of that method. Thank you for sharing. I've found a video on polynomial long division and will watch it before attempting to solve this problem.

Comment: *I wasn't aware of that method.* --- Polynomial division came before basic factoring methods (before common monomial factors, before difference of squares, etc.) when I took algebra 1 (1973-74, U.S.A. grade 9, students ages 14-15, used [Dolciani's **Algebra 1**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001JYSMKG)). In our text, polynomial (long) division was covered in the last section of Chapter 6 *Working with Polynomials* and various basic factor methods were covered in Chapter 7 *Special Products and Factoring*. I wonder if this difference is mainly due to historical differences or cultural differences?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation*}
P(x)=x^{6}-18x^{4}+42x^{3}+9x^{2}+19x+13
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
q(x)=x^{3}+5x^{2}+3
\end{equation*}
You are curious to know $C(x)$ and $K(x)$, where
\begin{equation}
P(x)=C(x)q(x)+K(x)\text{.}  
\end{equation}
Notice that $K(x)$ can easily be found by letting $q(x)=0$, i.e., $
x^{3}=-5x^{2}-3$, as, in this case, we will have $P(x)=K(x)$. Repeated
substitution of $x^{3}$ into the above equation yields
\begin{equation*}
K(x)=4x^{2}-2x+1\text{.}
\end{equation*}
So, the equation turns into
\begin{equation*}
P(x)=C(x)q(x)+4x^{2}-2x+1\text{,}
\end{equation*}
or equivalently,
\begin{equation}
 x^{6}-18x^{4}+42x^{3}+5x^{2}+21x+12=C(x)\times \left(
x^{3}+5x^{2}+3\right) \text{.}  \label{E2}
\end{equation}
Obviously, $C(x)$ must be of the form: $C(x)=x^{3}+ax^{2}+bx+4$.
Substituting $x=-1$ and $x=1$ into the last equation, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
 a-b=-12\text{ and }a+b=2\text{,}
\end{equation*}
which, in turn, give $a=-5$ and $b=7$. Thus, $C(x)=x^{3}-5x^{2}+7x+4$.

I hope this helps. Have a good day.